# ngFor in Angular making 5 divs and 5 uls -- instead of inside items

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular-directive, ngfor

The question is surprising behavior of ngFor and loopings items generated inside it.

I am making a simple example to refer *ngFor in Angular4/5/6. The issue is that I was expecting 1 div to contain 5 paragraph. I am amazed to see that I am getting instead 5 divs each containing 1 paragraph. Why is this and how to fix this? I am surprised **same is happening for ul-li items also**!!! -- strange.

**abc.component.html**

```
 <div *ngFor="let x of students">
   <p>{{x.name}}, {{x.age}}, {{x.country}}, {{x.gender}}</p>
 </div>
```

**abc.component.ts**

```
  students = [
    {name: "Jack", age: 29, gender:"male", country: "USA"},
    {name: "Ronald", age: 33, gender: "male", country: "UK"},
    {name: "Lisa", age: 19, gender: "female", country: "UK"},
    {name: "Donald", age: 43, gender: "male", country: "Austrailia"},
    {name: "Simera", age: 23, gender: "female", country: "Italy"}
  ];
```

**abc.component.css**

```
div{border:1px solid black;}
```

[image]

Even for ul-li (I am getting ul generated 5 times containing 1 li item in each)

```
<ul *ngFor="let x of students">
  <li>{{x.name}}, {{x.age}}</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: you need to loop paragraph tag not div tag

Comment: *Is* there a difference in behaviour? You don't actually show the output of the second example, which isn't quite correct syntax; I'd expect to see five ULs each containing one LI if it were written correctly.

Comment: After the edit: *why is any of that surprising?* That's exactly what you asked it to do, repeat the DIV/UL not the P/LI.

Comment: But, we used to do in AngularJS -- use ngFor in UL and then put child items in li --- same doing here is generating 5 ULs ... :-]

Comment: Maybe you should run through the basics of Angular, it's not all the same as AngularJS: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Don't ask for upvotes! That is not how this site is designed to work! Same goes for upvoting just to counter downvotes as you did with at least 2 answers below (and commented you did so). This is borderline vote fraud, I think which might get you suspended.

Comment: and what mass-downvoting ... by someone without a valid reason ? that's legal ?

Comment: @Deadpool: no, StackOverflow has some mechanisms in place if a user performs serial downvotes to "undo" this (probably within 24-48 hours). You can also flag in case you suspect somebody to given "undeserved" votes (both pro and con).

Comment: You were first asking about surprising behaviour of two things that looked the same behaving differently, which *would* indeed be surprising, except that they *didn't actually behave differently*. Now you're asking about surprising behaviour of two things that look the same *behaving the same*, which... doesn't seem at all surprising. Neither is a particularly useful question; the code is behaving as documented.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `ngFor` on `<p>` tag instead of `<div>` which will create 5 paragraph in one div.Like following:

```
<div>
   <p *ngFor="let x of students">{{x.name}}, {{x.age}}, {{x.country}}, {{x.gender}}</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ***ngFor** inside paragraph tag

```
<div>
   <p *ngFor="let x of students">
      {{x.name + ', ' + x.age + ', '+ x.country + ', '+ x.gender}}
   </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please review carefully 2 code snipped:

**//1**

```
 <div *ngFor="let x of students">
   <p>{{x.name}}, {{x.age}}, {{x.country}}, {{x.gender}}</p>
 </div>
```

**//2**

```
<ul ngFor="let x of students>
  <li>{{x.name}}, {{x.age}}</li>
</ul>
```

In 1: You wrote: *ngFor="..."

In 1: You wrote: ngFor="..."
      You must rewrite to: *ngFor="..."

**Hope to helpful!**